# Postgres select rows from table where variable in JSONB array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, where-clause

I'm trying to get rows in my DB where each contains a value in the JSONB column. What I have so far is

```
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE roles @> '[{"type": $2 }]'
```

Roles is a JSONB array and can have about 5 values.

What is the easiest way to get users that have an 'ADMIN' role. Postgres doesn't like the $2 and I can easily modify the query and insert the value as a string but don't want to add an opportunity for SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jsonb builder functions to generate a proper jsonb array; this allows properly passing the parameter:

```
select *
from users
where roles @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('type', $2))
```

Comment: Thx so much. Was messing around with other json functions that where slower or not usable with a parameter.